# How do I initiate a communication between a server and an app?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I found online an app to scan Access points around a cellphone and get **SSID** I added to it getting **Mac Address**, and **RSSI** Value.

I want to add to it getting tsf, and Last beacon.
you can see what I am looking for after running this command put your interface name instead of the Xs.

```
iwlist XXXX scan | grep 'ESSID\|Address\|Signal level\|Extra'
```

Also I want my server to initiate a request to the App to collecte the information about Access points around the devices without taking any action in the app as well as I want the app responses to the server with the information without taking any action in it.

[This](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/develop-a-wifi-scanner-android-application-daa3b77feb73) is the app I found online.

Comment: Usually people use push notifications for the server to initiate some action for the client. Also it is not clear what you want to do with those `XXXX `

Comment: this is a command line you can run through a terminal in your computer but you have to replace the XXXX with your network interface card name... thanks for answering me

Comment: are you sure that `iwlist` is available on Android?

Comment: No it is not .... I said above run it on your computer

Comment: so you want to scan networks on  Android, and run the command with the scanned networks on the computer?

Comment: this command line doesn't work in android system I put in my question to show you what I want my app to get if i run it.. i hope I cleared everything for you